# ¿Como validar un boton en javascript si tabla esta vacio que este inhabilitado?

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema con javascript ,en el detalle con el boton guardar, si no existe ningun item en la tabla para insertar , el boton guardar debe estar inhabilitado, si existe al menos un item para insertar , el boton guardar debe estar habilitado. Gracias

> En la imagen la tabla del detalle esta vacio, pero el boton esta activo cuando debe estar inhabilitado.
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> El de abajo es el Codigo de agregar detalle

```
$('#insert_detalle').on('click', function(){
    var item = $('#selectitem').val();
    var cantidad = $('#cantidad').val();
    if (item>0 && cantidad>0) { //valida requerido
        //$('#mensaje').html('<p></p>');
        var parametros = {
            'id' : $('#p0').val(),
            'cliente' : $('#p3').val(),
            'item' : $('#selectitem').val(),
            'cantidad' : $('#cantidad').val()
        };
        $.ajax({  //envia POST a otro php
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'pedido.detalles.add.php',
            data: parametros,
            success: function(data){
                    $('#selectitem option[value=0]').attr('selected',true);
                    $('#detalles').html(data);
                    $('#insertarDetalle').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $("#guardar").prop('disabled', false);


            }
        });
    } 
    else {
        //$('#mensaje').html('<p class="alert alert-danger">Descripcion es dato obligatorio!</p>');
        toastr["error"]("FALTAN ALGUNOS DATOS", "ATENCION");
    }
});
```

> Codigo borrar detalle

```
function quitarDetalle(id)

var parametros = {
    'id' : $('#id').val(),
    'cliente' : $('#cliente').val(),
    'item' : id
    };
if (confirm('Desea quitar producto?')) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'pedido.detalles.del.php',
        data: parametros,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#item').focus();
            $('#detalles').html(data);
            $("#guardar").prop('disabled', false);      
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que el botón no se active hasta que el detalle sea agregado tienes que ponerlo como disabled por default.

Por otro lado, un error que veo en tu código es que cuando llamas a la función que elimina el detalle el prop debería ser TRUE (tu lo tienes como false)

```
function quitarDetalle(id)

 var parametros = {
    'id' : $('#id').val(),
    'cliente' : $('#cliente').val(),
    'item' : id
};
if (confirm('Desea quitar producto?')) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'pedido.detalles.del.php',
        data: parametros,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#item').focus();
            $('#detalles').html(data);
            $("#guardar").prop('disabled', true);      
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: <input  type="button" id="guardar" class="btn btn-info"  value="Guardar" disabled="true" >            asi tengo el boton en el input. Igual sigue mi problema, el boton sigue habilitado, al borrar todos los items.